# Add link to content of JSSOR slide

Tags: hyperlink, jssor

I have html content in my JSSOR slides, and I would like to add a link  to the content.  Although the link displays fine I cannot click on it in the slide.

Is it possible to add a link to the content?  (I don't want to make the entire slide clickable).

I tried increase the z-index to 9999 but that didn't make a difference...

Answer (score 0):

```
<a style="display: block; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 150px; height: 30px;" href="url">link</a>
```

Comment: Doesn't work - I discovers that it relates to static content ("any" slide) - is there a workaround for this scenario?

Comment: The `any` element is parallel to slide elements, it is out of every slide. You can use it.